# PostgreSQL UPDATE substring replacement

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have a few rows in a test database where there are dollar signs prefixed to the value. I want to `UPDATE` the values in the `name` row of the `test1` table however when I threw the following query together it emptied the six rows of data in the `name` column...

```
UPDATE test1 SET name=overlay('$' placing '' from 1 for 1);
```

So "$user" became "" when I intended for that column/row value to become "user".

How do I combine UPDATE and a substr replacement without deleting any of the other data?

If there isn't a dollar sign I want the row to remain untouched.

The dollar sign only occurs as the first character when it does occur.

Comment: `name = replace(name, '$', '')`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you, that works. Not enough reputation to up-vote unfortunately though I'm curious how to do this if the dollar sign is the first character only? I tried this and it replaced dollar signs regardless of position. I tried `UPDATE test1 SET name = replace(name, '$', '', from 1 for 1);` without success; if you please post it as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you want to replace all dollar signs, use this:

```
update test1 
   set name = replace(name, '$', '');
```

If you want to replace the `$` only at the beginning of the value you can use `substr()` and a `where` clause to only change those rows where the column actually starts with a `$`

```
update test1 
    set name = substr(name, 2)
where name like '$%';
```

Comment: That was interesting, I hadn't considered using `substr`, I'm guessing it's not possible to combine `replace` with `FROM` then?

Comment: @user312854: no idea. I never got used to that form of the `replace()` function. For more complex replace tasks I usually use `regexp_replace()`

Comment: I can't think of any instances, at least offhand, where I'd need to consistently replace a character at a specific point between the first and last characters though I imagine that `replace` and `FROM` would be more efficient than using a regular expression? I'm fairly good at regex though avoid it unless I really have to to cut down on server load.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question using the pattern the OP had in mind.

```
UPDATE test1 SET name=overlay(name placing '' from 1 for 1)
WHERE name like '$%';
```