# Update a piece of string postgres

Tags: string, postgresql, sql-update

I have a system in which users have their permissions released in a column, positioned by user

> NNSNNNNNNNSNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNS

In the example above, users with codes 3 and 11 have access to a certain function, as they have the value 'S' in the string. I need an update in which I adjust a parameter in the substr for example, and that I update a certain position to the value 'S'

For example, changing the 32 position of the string to 'S' and keeping the rest as it is.
I tried:

```
update table_a set substr(column_a, 32, 1) = 'S'
```

But not work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSQL UPDATE substring replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27152413/postgresql-update-substring-replacement)

Answer (score 1):

I really don't recommend storing information in a string like that.  But that doesn't answer your question; `overlay()` does:

```
update table_a
    set column_a = overlay(column_a placing 'S' from 32 for 1);
```

You should have one row per user and permission.  That would be the correct way to store the information in a relational database.